# python: multiple barchart in subplot

Tags: python, bar-chart, subplot

In order to plot multiple barcharts I use the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 
X = ['Group A','Group B','Group C','Group D']
Ygirls = [10,20,20,40]
Zboys = [20,30,25,30]
  
X_axis = np.arange(len(X))
  
plt.bar(X_axis - 0.2, Ygirls, 0.4, label = 'Girls')
plt.bar(X_axis + 0.2, Zboys, 0.4, label = 'Boys')
  
plt.xticks(X_axis, X)
plt.xlabel("Groups")
plt.ylabel("Number of Students")
plt.title("Number of Students in each group")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

getting this result:

[image]

I would like to plot two of these figures attached to eachother, using the same y axis.
For a normal bar chart the code would be:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.bar(, )
ax2.bar(, )
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', length=0)
```

How do I modify the code for the multiple bar charts?

Comment: Maybe this could help https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a stacked bar dragram: you can view this example code [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html).
For your code, it would be like:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

X = ['Group A','Group B','Group C','Group D']
Ygirls = [10,20,20,40]
Zboys = [20,30,25,30]
X_axis = np.arange(len(X))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(X, Zboys, label = 'Boys')
ax.bar(X, Ygirls, label ='Grils', bottom=Zboys)
plt.xticks(X_axis, X)
plt.xlabel("Groups")
plt.ylabel("Number of Students")
plt.title("Number of Students in each group")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

And the output will be like:

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is not what I want. I would like to attach next to each other two figures, not to attach on each other the bars

Comment: So, you don't want the gap between two bars?